# Docusign API - prefilling tab values on envelope created from template

Tags: docusignapi

I was able to successfully generate and send an envelope from template using the Docusign API. The only problem is that the tab values and not pre-populating as expected (they remain blank). Here is the relevant code based on DocuSign-REST-API-Webinar-April2013:

```
/////////////////////////////////////////////
// STEP 2 - Create an envelope 
////////////////////////////////////////////

 $data = array(
        "accountId" => $accountId, 
        "emailSubject" => "DocuSign API - Signature Request from Template",
        "templateId" => $templateId, 
        "templateRoles" => array( 
            array( 
                "email" => $email, 
                "name" => $recipientName, 
                "inPersonSignerName" => "Some Customer", 
                "roleName" => "Customer", 
                "routingOrder" => 2,
                "tabs" => array(
                    "textTabs" => array(
                        array(
                            "tabLabel"=> "mmr",
                            "value" => "29.95"
                        ) 
                    )
                ) 
            ),
            array( 
                "email" => $email, 
                "name" => $recipientName, 
                "inPersonSignerName" => "Some Tech", 
                "roleName" => "Tech", 
                "routingOrder" => 1,
                "tabs" => array( 
                    "textTabs" => array ( 
                        array (
                            "tabLabel" => "\\*state",
                            "value" => "North Carolina"),
                        array (
                            "tabLabel" => "\\*city",
                            "value" => "Raleigh")
                    )
                )
            )
        ),
        "status" => "sent");
```

All my searches for answers on support forums, documentation, etc seem to point to what I have. I have double-checked the tabLabels and they are correct and assigned to the correct role. The template contains three roles - Tech (Sign In Person), Customer (Sign In Person), Data Entry (Receive a Copy).

Can anybody spot the problem? I also tried with just "tabLabel" => "state" and      "tabLabel" => "city" (i.e. without the wildcard) but same problem. Let me know if you need more info. Thanks!

Comment: Do you have the "Display SecureField initial value to all recipients" setting enabled on your account? You can find this under Preferences -> Features.

Answer (score 0):

Have you verified in the template that the tags are assigned to the expected recipient? Based on your code above, it looks like the tag labeled "mmr" should be assigned to the Customer role and the tags labeled "state" and "city" are assigned to the Tech. Is that correct?