# Ability to modify template tabs to have values in an envelope when a template is applied to an envelope

Tags: docusignapi

I am using docusign APIs to use an existing template when i send an envelope. In the Envelope definition (env), using env.setTemplateId(), i am able to set the template to the envelope. I want to be able to edit the tabs (to make them read-only and populate values) added through the template only in the context of the envelope (without modifying the template).
But on trying to retreive the envelope contents, the tabs are not listed as part of the envelope.
Any pointers on this? 
Have seen a few similar questions ([Docusign API - prefilling tab values on envelope created from template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26594354/docusign-api-prefilling-tab-values-on-envelope-created-from-template), [Docusign API - prefilling tab values on envelope created from template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26594354/docusign-api-prefilling-tab-values-on-envelope-created-from-template)), but no concrete solution yet.

Answer (score 1):

By default GET on an envelope would not retrieve the tabs. You can do that by making [this API call](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/reference/Envelopes/EnvelopeDocumentTabs/get):

```
GET /restapi/v2.1/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes/{envelopeId}/documents/{documentId}/tabs
```

Which requires that you know the documentID.

If you are using one of our SDKs, you can see code examples that do just that here:

https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/code-examples/set-template-tab-values